# Trying to remove rows based on values in two columns

Tags: r, row

My data is formatted something like this:

```
 name  value1  rem 
-------------------
| tom  | 1   |  1
| tom  | 3   |  0
| tom  | 5   |  0
| bill | 7   |  0
| bill | 1   |  1
| bill | 3   |  0
| mark | 5   |  0
| mark | 9   |  0
| mark | 9   |  0
```

What I'm trying to do is remove any row that has a 1 in "rem" and any row that has the same ID as a row with 1 in "rem." So after the transformation I want it would look like:

```
 name  value1  rem 
-------------------
| mark | 5   |  0
| mark | 9   |  0
| mark | 9   |  0
```

I can't figure out how to do this in R using a logic command. My actual data has far more rows and columns so I can't just delete them by location, i.e. just deleting the first 6 rows. I get how to delete any row with a specific value. What I can't figure out is how to delete rows based on values in two rows one of which is conditional. Here is some R code that made a data frame like above:

```
name <- c("tom", "tom", "tom", "bill", "bill","bill","mark","mark","mark")
value1 <- c(1,3,5,7,1,3,5,9,9)
rem <- c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
df <- data.frame(name, value1, rem)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this:

```
# get the names that has 1 rem
# then identify names not in that subset and 
# use it to subset the df
df[!(df$name %in% df$name[df$rem == 1]), ]
```

Comment: In a similar way, `subset(df, !name %in% name[rem == 1])` or `df %>%
    filter(!name %in% name[rem == 1])` will do.

Comment: Thank you that worked like a charm. I'm not sure I 100% understand the command. What I'm getting is (from the outside in): the "df[,] part is returning all of some subset or rows. The "!" is saying "not" whatever follows. "df$name %in%" is checking if each row of "df$name" is in what follows. Finally, "df$name[df$rem == 1]" returns a list of all the "df$name" values for which "df$rem" is equal to one. So the inner parenthesis returns all rows where the name in the row is in the list of names with rem=1. Is that about right?

Comment: Yep that's it. `df$name[df$rem == 1])` gives names with rem = 1. `df$name %in% df$name[df$rem == 1]` identify which name is on the right, these are all logicals (like you said) and the `!` just negate it so that you will have names not with rem = 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)
newdf<- df %>%
  group_by(name)%>%
  summarise(rem = sum(rem))

newdf2<-filter(newdf, rem<1)
```